# ASIHTTPRequest returns error 406 when trying to read RSS Feed

Tags: iphone, ios, http, rss, asihttprequest

I'm trying to read the following URL: http://www.bandsintown.com/Godwrath/rss

My response string is empty and `[request responseStatusCode]` returns 406. I've tried adding the following with no success:

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/xml"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/rss+xml"];
```

Have any of you ever bumped into this problem?

Greets,
Shai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CharlesProxy (or wireshark, or ...) to capture the http traffic from:

1. Your iOS app
2. A working client (eg. a web browser)

Compare the 2 and try to correct any differences (you can probably ignore User-Agent:, Connection:, If-Modified-Since: and a few other headers)

If you still can't get it working edit your question to add in the request captured in charlesproxy from the browser, your changed code to create the request and the request captured from your app.

Comment: Adding User-Agent: Apple-PubSub/65.28 did the job, i'm not exactly sure why but it works ;-) thanks for the suggestion on CharlesProxy!

Answer (score 0):

406 generally means your browser doesn't understand the return data from the web server. In the example you give, you overwrite the Accept header. You can't provide the same header tag twice if I remember correctly...